# Tab key prints an " i " to the console instead of executing tab complete

Tags: linux, bash

I have been using Linux for 27 hours now and I am just now getting aquainted with the command line interface. In my instruction, tab complete should execute the remainder of a directory name such as desktop when I perform

```
cd \D[TAB]
```

In my mind, this should compele the rest of the statement such as 'Desktop'. Instead, I get

```
code cd \D
```

The tab key works as it should in my Windows environment but not in this Toolwire virtual environment where Red Had Linux is installed.

I just want to get an idea of what's going on here. Right now I have no direction and dont know where to begin to troublshoot this. I've tried going into accessibility to see if there is a way to change this as well as keyboard shortcuts to see if I could change the tab functionality that way.

I'm hoping for some insight.

---

I tried another generic PS/2 keyboard thinking that maybe the wireless keyboard I was using was the cause of the issue. I went over the steps given to me by a poster and came up with this. I'm starting to suspect this toolwire environment, now.

This is a big deal because I want to expereince tab complete. According to the instructions I simply say: cd \home\student\ hit D hit TAB and esktop should populate. That easy, right?

I really just wanted to rule out syntax and semantics before I started looking at the environment. I always have my own software so I haven't had a need for this thing until now. I'm just trying to avoid a dual boot before I can really sink my teeth into the fundamentals.

Comment: 27 hours?! take a break!

Comment: Try `cd /D[TAB]` instead ... Windows is the only OS that still uses backslash.

Comment: I tried cd /D[TAB] and get the same "i". In fact, the tab key doesn't do anything it is supposed to in this toolwire environment. It's a shame because I just got started and already hit a wall.

There are some directories with other people's name on them in this installation and I'm wondering if they've done something to affect the tab key's functionality, and if so, is there any way to set this stuff back to a 'default'?

Comment: Desktop is in /home/your_username/Desktop or in Desktop (from your home) but not in /Desktop

Comment: Ed, your question didn't have anything to do with programming and was thus migrated from Stack Overflow to a site where it's absolutely on topic. There's no reason to delete your question – it has a much better home here.

Answer (score 1):

/ is the root directory, and there is no Desktop in there.
Try it with the current directory './Desktop', or with the full path to your home directory '/home/student/Desktop'.

Comment: Moreover, if there are 2 directories starting with D and having different characters after the D, you need to press Tab 2 times: the first does nothing, the second lists the possible completions.